# Flutter || Data from HTML Rendered , But Selectable Text Widget not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flutter, webview, mobile-application

I was using this Package to render data which comes as a string format into CustomStylesBuilder ...
using the customWidgetBuilder , it is not allowing us to select the Data which is formatted and styled properly ...
So it is not serving my purpose ,.,,, please look into it ...

Package used : **flutter_widget_from_html_core**

If there is any alternate packages that allows us to use **SelectableText **and **customStylesBuilder** at the same time , please suggest ....

- **IN MOBILE-FLUTTER**

I expected a package that helps us to select the HtmlContent after getting styled ,
But it is not helping me ,
If you guys have any suggestion / KNowledge , on how to achieve it ... please help ...

inplace of html-data-string-blocs please use some dummy HTML Data as a string ...

```
// My-Class-Init-State
@override
  void initState() {
    dataField = widget.clauseInfo?.data;
    for(String element in (widget.htmlDataList!=null)? 
     widget.htmlDataList!:[]){
      concatenatedStrings ='$concatenatedStrings$element';
    }
    log('concatenatedStrings - $concatenatedStrings');
    htmlString = concatenatedStrings;
    /* ~~~ From API,Un-comment after use ~~~ */
    modifiedHtml = replaceTextInSpan(htmlString,(dataField!=null)? 
  dataField:null);
    mapData = (widget.clauseInfo?.data!=null)?jsonDecode("$dataField"):{};
    mapData.forEach((key, value) {
    Map<String,Style>? m = {
      "$key": Style(
        fontSize: FontSize(18.0),
        color: AppColors.filterTextColor,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      )};
    mapStringToStyle.addEntries(m.entries);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

String removeHtmlTags(String htmlString) {
 RegExp exp = RegExp(r'<[^>]*>', multiLine: true, caseSensitive:true);
 return htmlString.replaceAll(exp, '');
}

dynamic traverseInnerTags(String htmlString) {
    dom.DocumentFragment document = parser.parseFragment(htmlString);
    dynamic traverseNodes(dom.Node node) {
      if (node is dom.Element) {
        /* ~~~ Handle the link tap event here ~~~ */
        // _launchURL('${node.attributes['href']}');
        if(node.localName == 'td') {
          if(node.localName == 'a') {
            return SelectableText('${node.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 17,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
          }
        }
        if (node.localName == 'p') {
          return SelectableText(node.text.replaceAll('\u00a0', ' '),style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,fontFamily: 'Roboto',),textAlign: TextAlign.justify,);
        } if (node.localName == 'h3'){
          return SelectableText('${node.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 17,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
        } if (node.localName == 'h2'){
          return SelectableText('${node.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 19,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
        } if (node.localName == 'h4'){
          return SelectableText('${node.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
        } if(node.localName == 'strong'){
          return SelectableText('${node.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
        } if (node.localName == '&nbsp'||node.localName == '\n'){
          return const SelectableText('\n');
        }   
        node.nodes.forEach(traverseNodes);
        return null;
      }
      return null;
    }
    document.nodes.forEach(traverseNodes);
    return null;
  }



// *** Build-Context-Function *** //

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
          child: HtmlWidget(
            concatenatedStrings,
            customStylesBuilder: (element) {
                if(element.localName == 'table'){
                  return {
                    'width': '100%',
                    'height': '100%',
                    'border': '1px double #b3b3b3',
                    'border-collapse': 'collapse',
                    'border-spacing': '0',
                  };
                }
                if(element.localName == 'figure'){
                  return {
                    'width': '100%',
                    'margin': '.9em auto'
                  };
                }
                if(element.localName == 'td'){
                  if(element.children == ['h2']){
                    return {
                      'border': '1px solid #bfbfbf',
                      'min-width': '2em',
                      'padding': '0.4em',
                      'text-align' : 'right'
                    };
                  }
                  return {
                    'border': '1px solid #bfbfbf',
                    'min-width': '2em',
                    'padding': '0.4em',
                    'text-align' : 'right'
                  };
                }
                if (element.localName == 'th' || element.localName == 'tr') {
                  return {
                    // 'border': '0.0px solid none',
                    // 'padding': '2px',
                  };
                } 
                if (element.classes.contains('mention')) {
                  return {
                    'color': 'black', 
                    'font-size': '17px',
                    'font-family':'sans-serif',
                    'font-weight':'bold'
                  };
                } if (element.localName == 'p') {
                  return {
                    'color': 'black', 
                    'font-size': '16px',
                    'font-family':'Roboto',
                    'text-align' : 'justify'
                  };
                } 
                if (element.localName == 'p') {
                  return {
                    'color': 'black', 
                    'font-size': '16px',
                    'font-family':'Roboto',
                    'text-align' : 'justify'
                  };
                } 
                if (element.localName!.contains('h3') || element.localName!.contains('h2') || element.localName!.contains('h4') || element.localName!.contains('h1') ||element.localName!.contains('h5') || element.localName!.contains('h6')) {
                  return {
                    'color': 'black', 
                    'font-size': '16px',
                    'font-family':'Roboto',
                    'font-weight': '500',
                    'text-align' : 'justify'
                  };
                } 
                if(element.localName == 'img'){
                  final src = element.attributes['src'];
                  if (src != null) {
                    return {
                      'display': 'block',
                      'max-width': '100%',
                      'height': 'auto',
                    };
                  }
                }
                // null;
            },
            customWidgetBuilder: (element) {
              if(element.localName==''){}
              SelectableText('${element.text} \n',style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontFamily: 'Roboto'),);
            //  traverseInnerTags(concatenatedStrings);
            //   return null;
            },
          ),
          
        ),
      );
    }**strong text**
```